# how to make after solve recaptcha then visible the clickable button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to make a page like after solve reCAPTCHA then visible the clickable button?

I don't know about JavaScript and jQuery but I want to add this on my next website, When visitors visit my page he need to wait solve reCAPTCHA then visible the next page button.

Like this image:

[image]

Comment: Your question is to broad.  You should ask something more specific.  Try  looking at recaptcha tutorials

Answer (score 0):

1.add jquery cdn to your page (if there is no)

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

2.Add reCaptha,
3.Add Submit button

```
<input type="submit"id="btnSubmit"value="Submit"/>
```

4.write script

```
   <script>
    window.onload=function(){
    var recaptcha = $("#g-recaptcha-response").val();
    recaptcha.required = true;
    if (recaptcha === "") { 
     event.preventDefault(); 
     $("#btnSubmit").attr("disabled", "disabled");;//To disable the button
         } 
      }
//Now enable button after complete the captha
 $("#g-recaptcha-response").change(function(){
     if (recaptcha != "") { 
      $("#btnSubmit").removeAttr('disabled');
    })
        </script>
```